# What is causing this error when I try to edit a RoR object that was created via scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is causing this error when I click on the edit button for a note? The delete button works fine. I created the note object with a scaffold.

index.html.erb

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
    <%= note.detail %>
    <%= button_to 'Delete', note, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    <%= button_to 'Edit', edit_note_path(note) %>
<% end %>
```

notes_controller.rb

```
before_filter :check_ownership, :except => [:new, :create, :index, :edit]
def edit
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
end
```

Error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in NotesController#192 
Couldn't find Note with ID=edit
../app/controllers/notes_controller.rb:248:in `check_ownership'
Parameters:
{"id"=>"edit"}
```

EDIT
config/routes.rb

```
map.resources :notes
```

All of the other routes for notes work fine.

Thanks for reading

Comment: please post the output of `rake routes | grep note`, or the part for this routes from your `config/routes.rb`. There seems to be something wrong with your route creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaffold controller's 'edit' action, and defult routing support 'edit' as GET rather than POST request.

If you use `link_to` rather than `button_to`, things should work.

Alternatively, change the line containing `button_to`  -

```
<%= button_to 'Edit', edit_note_path(note), :method => :get %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! If it's not too much trouble, could I ask why there's a difference between link_to and button_to?

Comment: hey ben, link_to generates a simple hyperlink (<a href="...">...</a>), the default request generated by this is a GET. whereas button_to generates a whole form structure, with a 'submit' button within it. forms default action type is POST.

I think the difference between the default request types for hyperlinks (GET) and form buttons (POST) is beyond rail's control - this is HTML.

Comment: Ah, I get it know. Thanks for the help!